# Adding ext-stackdriver_debugger to composer to enable StackDriver debugging in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, composer-php, stackdriver

I'm following the steps on this page: https://cloud.google.com/debugger/docs/setup/php

I want to set up the debugging for App Engine flexible environment (PHP 7.2).

Step 3 says to add the `Add the Stackdriver Debugger PHP extension via your composer.json file:` with the following command:

```
composer require ext-stackdriver_debugger:*
```

However, when I run that, the package cannot be found:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]                                                                                                                                                   
  Could not find a matching version of package ext-stackdriver_debugger. Check the 
  package spelling, your version constraint and that the package is available in a
  stability which matches your minimum-stability (stable).
```

How can I complete Step 3 successfully?

Comment: Are you sure you've enabled this extension in your PHP? Is it on the list of enabled modules if you run `php -m`?

Comment: @rob006 Ah, that was it. I had added it to my GAE's php.ini, but not to the php.ini that was being used by my command-line php. Once I added it to that php.ini then the command worked. Thanks! If you post this as a real answer, then I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such error usually means that extension/module is not enabled in PHP version used by `composer` command. Make sure that you've enabled module in `php.ini` used by PHP CLI. Alternatively you may explicitly use specific PHP version to run `composer` command:

```
/usr/bin/php7.2 composer require ext-stackdriver_debugger:*
```

---

In worst case you may try to add extension manually to `composer.json`:

```
"require": {
    "ext-stackdriver_debugger": "*",
    ...
},
```

and use `--ignore-platform-reqs` switch on `composer update` and `composer install`. Or just ignore this step - requiring PHP extension does not give you any real benefits except preventing installing package on server without this extension. You don't need to add PHP extension to `composer.json` to use it.